# iPhone app autorotates on one device, but not another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Does anyone know of a reason why an iPhone would autorotate on one device, but not another? I can't reproduce it on my iPhone, iPod Touch, or any of the simulator devices.

Are there any device settings I should be paying attention to? The offending iPhone has the same SDK version installed (4.2.1), but is a different model (MC319LL) than mine (MC605DN).

Comment: Getting the obvious out of the way: The rotation lock isn't on, is it?

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of the rotation lock. Unfortunately, I'm still not able to reproduce the autorotation on my phone after enabling/disabling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never figured out why the two phones were acting differently, but this bit of code in in the UITabBarController subclass seems to have solved things:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made sure that the misbehaving device had its rotation lock turned off in the settings, right?

Comment: No, I didn't, but the misbehaving device was rotating more than it should have been, so I'm assuming that it wasn't related. Big assumption, I realize.